# Split de palavras com find_if

Tags: c++

Como é montada essa string(i, j)? a primeira string inserida no vector é "Robison" e está correta, porém para ter esse resulta o valor de i deveria ser 0 e j = 7, não?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// predicate (split)
bool space(char c)
    { return isspace(c); }

// preticate (split)
bool not_space(char c)
    { return !isspace(c); }

vector<string> split(const string& str)
{
    typedef string::const_iterator iter;
    vector<string> ret;

    iter i = str.begin();
    while (i != str.end())
    {
        // verifica se o caracter e espaço
        i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space);

        // procura um novo carácter
        iter j = find_if(i, str.end(), space);

        // faz a cópia dos caracteres encontrados
        if (i != str.end())
            ret.push_back(string(i, j));
        i = j;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main ()
{
    string str = "Robison Aleixo";
    split(str);

    return 0;
}

/*
 *  Basicamente as declarações acima encontram o range de uma string
    armazena as strings em um vetor "removendo" os espaços em branco
 *
 *  Exemplo: str= "Robison Aleixo"
 *
 *  iter i = str.begin();  ::::> i  será = 0
 *  while (i != str.end()) ::::> será executado até o último caracter da string
 *  i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space);  ::::> i = 6
 *  iter j = find_if(i, str.end(), space); ::::> j = 7
 *  if i != str.end())  ::::> Verifica se não é o último caracter
 *  ret.push_back(string(i, j));  ::::> i = 6 ; j = 7
 *
 *  R o b i s o n   A l e  i  x  o
 *  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
 *              ^ ^
 *              i j
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i deveria ser 0 e j = 7, não?

São de facto esses os valores. Se olharmos para como é obtido o `i`:

```
i = find_if(i, str.end(), not_space /*<--not space aqui!*/);
```

Atente no `not_space`, logo mal começa apanha o primeiro caractere que **não é espaço**, e por isso a primeira letra, a da posição `0` e não a posição `6` como tinha indicado.

Logo de seguida apanhamos o espaço a seguir para o `j` com:

```
iter j = find_if(i, str.end(), space);
```

Agora sim utilizamos o predicado de `space` para apanhar o espaço. Se ainda não chegamos ao fim utilizamos o construtor da `string` que recebe dois iteradores e inicia a `string` com o texto entre eles:

```
string(i, j)
```

E dado na documentação como:

> `template <class InputIterator> string (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`
>
> (7) range constructor Copies the sequence of characters in the range
>   [first,last), in the same order.

É importante de notar que o ultimo elemento, o `last`, não é incluído, o que calha bem no algoritmo pois faz com que a `string` construída não contenha o espaço que estava em `j`

Comment: Verdade na própria documentação diz: _Returns an iterator to the first element in the range [first,last) for which pred returns true. If no such element is found, the function returns last._

Eu me confundi, estava pensando que ele ia testando o _predicate_ até retornar falso. Obrigado pela ajuda!